# Graphing libraries for F# that offer most control over the appearance of a plot

Tags: plot, f#

I've recently begun the conversion from using `R` to using `F#` for analysis and creating figures.  In `R`, I used the `ggplot2` library exclusively as I could control most, if not all, aspects of the plot.  Fonts, legend placement, line weight/type, axes, fill; they were all easily controlled with `ggplot2`.  Further, I could easily export figures created with `ggplot2` to a .png file for use, well, anywhere else.

As a recent `F#` convert, I've been looking for something similar to `ggplot2`.  I can't seem to find it.  I've explored

- [Xplot.Plotly](https://www.nuget.org/packages/XPlot.Plotly/)
- [XPlot.GoogleCharts](https://www.nuget.org/packages/XPlot.GoogleCharts/)
- [FSharp.Charting](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Charting)
- [FnuPlot](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FnuPlot/)

These all seem to be very popular for web-based uses (come on: `XPlot` is *super* cool for web-based stuff!) but I'm most interested in creating static plots that will be embedded in `.pdf` documents, thus my need to export to `.png` and the need to have as much control over the appearance of a plot as possible.

I've used the `RProvider` library to dip back into `R` and to use `ggplot2` and the `qplot()` function, but I'd like to move away from `R` entirely.

Are there other popular graphing libraries that I've missed that offer control over the appearance and can be easily exported/saved to a `.png` file?

Comment: I don't recall other F#-based charting libraries. However, since FnuPlot is just a wrapper for GnuPlot -- which certainly allows you to control basically anything -- this should give you the needed flexibility, perhaps by using the ``SendCommand`` function. Also, I seem to recall that FSharp.Charting lets you control certain things by pressing Ctrl + G, when the chart is open (but maybe I remember incorrectly).

Comment: Using OxyPlot easily save the chart in .png.